# cannot deduce lambda function template argument

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have this template function declared locally in my source file:

```
template<typename T>
const std::wstring test(std::function<const std::wstring(T)> f, T arg)
{
    return f(arg);
}
```

and I try to use it in the subsequent function like this:

```
auto run = [](const std::string address) -> const std::wstring { return L""; };
test(run, address);
```

but the compiler complains that it cannot deduce the template argument for lambda "run". what am I doing wrong?

the compiler says:

```
error C2784: 'const std::wstring test(std::function<const std::wstring(T)>,T)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::function<const std::wstring(T)>' from 'xxx::<lambda_d434160cf17ec6991f6c12a43474f9a9>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need

```
std::function<const std::wstring(std::string)> run =
    [](const std::string address) { return L""; };
```

A lambda has its own generated type (`xxx::<lambda_d434160cf17ec6991f6c12a43474f9a9>` in your case), and with `auto`, `run` keeps this type. On the other hand, `test` expects a `std::function<const std::wstring(T)>`.

Simpler (and more efficient), you could make `test` a template on the function type:

```
template<typename F, typename T>
const std::wstring test(F f, T arg) { return f(arg); }
```

Comment: +1 for the suggested improved template function, thanks!

Comment: Yes, this “Simpler (and more efficient)...” approach is **very** helpful insight! That had not occurred to me. It feels like “Here is a function. Don't worry about its type. Just call it like this.”